# How can I switch to cmd/powershell when debug in CLion?

Tags: c++, c, clion

After I updated CLion the debug mode did not use system console (cmd/powershell) instead it uses CLion built-in console. How can I switch to system console in debug mode?

Comment: What is the problem you have with the built-in console? Why do you want to switch?

Comment: @Some programmer dude I have problem with ```printf```, it can't print out anything. If I use ```cout``` it still can't print anything unless I use ```endl```.

Comment: First of all, why do you use `printf` when programming in C++? Secondly, for the `printf` calls do you end the output with a newline (`'\n'`)? Remember that output to `stdout` (which `printf` writes to) is by default *line-buffered*. The newline *flushes* the output. The same with `std::endl`, it adds a newline *and* flushes the output.

Comment: @Some programmer dude I'm not programming in c++ and I know printf end with ```\n``` will flush the buffer. Even if I add ```\n``` it didn't print out anything. I also need something like ```Input: ``` so I can't add a ```\n``` in the end of string.

Comment: Your tags say you do.

Comment: Just to clarify, it's the console for input and output when you are *debugging* your application? Not just when running the application?

Comment: @Some programmer dude Yep, when I run the application the built-in console works well.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what's going on.

Output to `stdout` is line-buffered *by default*, right? But that's only valid when `stdout` is connected directly to the console. When it's not, like for example when it's connected to a pipe, then it's *fully* buffered.

I'm guessing that is what happens here.

My guess is based on the fact that calling `fflush(stdout)` after a `printf` call flushes the buffer and the output is written on the console as expected.

If there's no ticket [in the CLion bug-tracking system](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP) about the issue, then it should definitely be added.

Comment: It works with ```fflush(stdout)```. I wonder if it can switch to system console because before I updated CLion it will always open a system console for debugging.

Comment: [I've added a bug-report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-11773)